# Data not getting deleted using $http in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

While calling an api through $http service in Angular JS to delete message, I get success as response but value is not getting deleted . But when I tried the same api directly in browser the message gets deleted.

My Code is as follows

```
  var del_mail = server.url + "api/app/mobifunctions/inbox/delete_message.html?contactid=" + conId + "&token=" + token + "&exid=" + exId +"&message_id=" + selectedIds + "&action=deleted";
            $http.get(del_mail).success(function(response) {
                if(response[0].status =="success"){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                    alert("You have Successfully deleted the messaage(s)");
                    $route.reload();
                }
            });
```

Please assist.

Comment: errr, what kind of messed up API has you `GET` a `DELETE` command?

Comment: Yip, beware of web crawlers deleting messages. And when you say the message is not deleted, can you elaborate. Does the message remain on the view or does the message remain on the server?

Comment: Is the service call using Angular hitting your service ? Please check while you call the service through angular app it is hitting the service on the server side. If no then it could be a caching issue.

Comment: You can elaborate a bit more for understanding it in better way. But check with api team as well and check you parameter's has any special characters which are changing your url or inspect url from network tab and make sure you are passing correct values for url

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is designed to deal with restful API

meaning that we use

```
GET => read records e
POST => create record
PUT  => update record
DELETE => delete record
```

here is a good article explaining all about REST and html:

[http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340](http://REST%20article)

you can also check this slide for the connection between angularJS and servers

[http://fr.slideshare.net/moralescarlos1/angular-js-zrh-connect-server-39048472?related=2](http://how%20to%20connect%20angularJS%20with%20servers)